# Symfony Elastic mapping

Tags: php, symfony, foselasticabundle

I have mapping for entity for field "skills"

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="skills", type="array", nullable=true)
 * @Groups({"for_profile_project"})
 */
private $skills = [];
```

elastic config (this is my all config [postebin](http://pastebin.com/TkJRt1PN))

teams:

```
    indexes:
    profile:
        finder: ~
        types:
            team:
                 mappings:
                     id:
                       type: integer
                     slug:
                       type: string
                   projects:
                        type: "nested"
                        properties:
                             id: ~
                             title:
                                type: string
                             description:
                                type: string
                             skills:
                                expose: true
                 persistence:
                      driver: orm
                      model: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Teams
                      provider: ~
                      listener:
                        immediate: true
                      finder: ~
```

and in DB I have like this

```
a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:10:"JavaScript";s:7:"percent";d:44.169475214305216;}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:3:"CSS";s:7:"percent";d:37.235383527019629;}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:3:"PHP";s:7:"percent";d:10.312846145221229;}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:4:"HTML";s:7:"percent";d:8.1084777328220206;}i:4;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:10:"ApacheConf";s:7:"percent";d:0.17381738063190688;}}
```

and when I update entity I have error

```
Merging dynamic updates triggered a conflict: mapper [projects.skills.percent] of different type, current_type [double], merged_type [long]
```

what type of I need for field skills or how to correct elastic config?
what's wrong with my config?

I deleted all inde in my elastic and run command

```
app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset
```

and now I have this mapping

```
"team": {
"properties": {
  "skills": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "webSite": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
    "type": "date"
  },
  "projects": {
    "properties": {
      "cost": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "authorId": {
        "properties": {
          "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "username": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "skills": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
```

and now I create test project with one skill(a:1:{i:0;s:6:"skills";}) but automatic not upload in elastic only when I edit entity team or run command

```
app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset
```

and when I add real project with

```
a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:10:"JavaScript";s:7:"percent";d:44.169475214305216;}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:3:"CSS";s:7:"percent";d:37.235383527019629;}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:3:"PHP";s:7:"percent";d:10.312846145221229;}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:4:"HTML";s:7:"percent";d:8.1084777328220206;}i:4;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:10:"ApacheConf";s:7:"percent";d:0.17381738063190688;}}
```

and run

```
app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset
```

or when I add for this entity team nested entity developer I have error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion

mapper_parsing_exception

failed to parse [projects.skills]

illegal_argument_exception

unknown property [lang]
```

I try set percent like integer but still have error

```
a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:10:"JavaScript";s:7:"percent";d:44;}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:3:"CSS";s:7:"percent";d:37;}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:3:"PHP";s:7:"percent";d:10;}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:4:"HTML";s:7:"percent";d:8;}i:4;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:10:"ApacheConf";s:7:"percent";d:0;}}
```

I try

```
                                 skills:
                                  expose: true
                                  properties:
                                      lang:
                                          type: string
                                      percent:
                                          type: double
```

but still have

```
      Notice: Array to string conversion

mapper_parsing_exception

failed to parse [projects.skills]

illegal_argument_exception

unknown property [lang]
```

**UPDATE**

Now I deleted index and change config like this:

```
                                skills:
                                  properties:
                                      lang:
                                          type: string
                                      percent:
                                          type: double
```

and in elastic

```
          "skills": {
        "properties": {
          "lang": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "percent": {
            "type": "double"
          }
        }
      },
```

and when I upload entity with field skills like this :

```
a:5:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:10:"JavaScript";s:7:"percent";d:44.169475214305216;}i:1;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:3:"CSS";s:7:"percent";d:37.235383527019629;}i:2;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:3:"PHP";s:7:"percent";d:10.312846145221229;}i:3;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:4:"HTML";s:7:"percent";d:8.1084777328220206;}i:4;a:2:{s:4:"lang";s:10:"ApacheConf";s:7:"percent";d:0.17381738063190688;}}
```

everything ok but when I create entity with field

```
a:1:{i:0;s:8:"skills23";}
```

I have error

**UPDATE**

```
                             skills:
                               expose: true
                             github:
                                  properties:
                                      lang:
                                          type: string
                                      percent:
                                          type: double
```

Why field github not create in elastic I not understand 
(this is my all config [postebin](http://pastebin.com/TkJRt1PN))

Comment: are you sure, your previous indexed data didn't presented as long for "projects.skills.percent" ? For dynamic mapping first data defines the mapping, Please check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html

Comment: update my question. what's wrong with my config? or how to do dynamic type?

Comment: Your skills already dynamic mapped but you have to be sure you mustn't send different types for 'percent' You did send int/long data before this example data. If you are not sure did you send or not please send `DELETE /your-index-name/_mapping` to delete mapping and send your data again. If you encounter same problem again, please check your data especially 'percent' There have to be a data which is sending as int/long. Use all of the percents as double example `percent : 1` Wrong. `percent : 1.0` correct. It is have to be for 0 values too. `percent : 0.0`

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Could you share full foselastic config ? There may be indentation issue.

Comment: yes, http://pastebin.com/TkJRt1PN

Comment: I create field github and config in elastic with properties, but have error. And only when I config in elastci field github like expose: treu and run elastic popolation I sse this field in elastic maping then I change - add properties lang and percent and in elastic mapng I have field github with properties

Comment: OK, is github is a data which is child of skills in your database or is this a column ? If it is data, you cannot map a data. you can just map columns. I see you changed skills to expose again. What is the purpose ?

Comment: I map only fields(column) entity. Now I have skills = [] for one type ptoject and github = [] got another type project and now work fine. I think use expose: true for array this is norm or not ?  But I have another problen when I create entity "developer"( index talent) in my elastic not upload nested entity "user". Only when I enter in profile and some change information about "developer" I see "user" in elastic. For entity "teams"(index teams) this problem too - not upload nested entity until I some change entity "teams"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"skills": {
    "type": "string"
  },`

defined as string in your mapping, but in your data skills is an array with keys lang and percent so your partial mapping for skills should be.

```
"skills": {
    "properties" : {
        "lang" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "percent" : {
            "type" : "double"
        },
    }
},
```

Edited : It should work.

```
indexes:
profile:
    finder: ~
    types:
        team:
             mappings:
                 id:
                   type: integer
                 slug:
                   type: string
               projects:
                    type: "nested"
                    properties:
                         id: ~
                         title:
                            type: string
                         description:
                            type: string
                         skills:
                            properties:
                              lang:
                                type: string
                              percent:
                                type: double
             persistence:
                  driver: orm
                  model: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Teams
                  provider: ~
                  listener:
                    immediate: true
                  finder: ~
```

Comment: I updated my answer. You were used expose: true I removed that line and defined the required mapping fields under skills

Comment: Btw, you should aware it is not working with dynamic mapping now, we are pre define the mapping.

Comment: I try your example config, but stiil have error . Now I try again deleted index in elastic and try again app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset

Comment: Could you please clarify last error which you have ?

Comment: all ok. I deleted index in elastic and run app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset and everything ok. Only when I create tean I have upload in elastic only fields entity team, nested entity not upload only when I run app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset. Maybe you know what this problem ?

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly, Do you mean you changed your structure and mapping didn't updated ? If it is, you must remove and reindex your data when you have to change data structure, Data structure changes invalidates all of your indexes, even particular structure changes.

Comment: I again have problem I create project for a:1:{i:0;s:8:"skills23";} and have error. How to correct config ?

Comment: shuba I think you can overcome the problem. Just make some research. For hint, is i int everytime ? is s string everytime ? if not make them same for every record, and define your config according to it, like we did.

Comment: now I shared skills and github skills. And when I run  app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset but in elastic in mapping not create field github. I deleted index but stiil not create. I update question